# Mejorar Seguridad Inicio de Sesion PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, login

necesito que me ayuden a reforzar la seguridad del siguiente codigo, como es el codigo de una aplicacion grande, necesito consejos y todo lo que sea util para que sea muy dificil de hackear. Esta creado con PHP PDO y usa MySQL como motor de base de datos.

Hola, necesito que me ayuden a reforzar la seguridad del siguiente codigo, como es el codigo de una aplicacion grande, necesito consejos y todo lo que sea util para que sea muy dificil de hackear. Esta creado con PHP PDO y usa MySQL como motor de base de datos.

```
<?php  session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user_nombre_usuario']) && isset($_SESSION['user_codigo_identificacion'])) {

    session_regenerate_id();

        header("Location: ../usuario/");

        exit();

}elseif (isset($_SESSION['nombre_empresa']) && isset($_SESSION['codigo_identificacion_comercio'])) {

    session_regenerate_id();

        header("Location: ../panel/");

    exit();

}

$error_login = '';


if (isset($_POST['validador-acceso'])) {

//Validamos si se enviaron los datos correctamente

    if (isset($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {

    //Validamos si el campo ingresado esta vacio o no

        if (empty($_POST['usuario']) && empty($_POST['password'])) {

            //Colocamos el mensaje de error

                $error_login = 'Los datos ingresados no pueden estar vacios';

        }else{

            //Limpiamos los datos recibidos

        require_once '../../assets/0/config.php';

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------//

                $usuario_cross = $_POST['usuario'];

                $usuario_mysql = $mysqli->real_escape_string($usuario_cross);

                $usuario_trim = trim($usuario_mysql);

                $usuario_slc = htmlentities($usuario_trim);

                $usuario_usuario = htmlspecialchars($usuario_slc);

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------//

                $password_cross = $_POST['password'];

                $password_mysql = $mysqli->real_escape_string($password_cross);

                $password_trim = trim($password_mysql);

                $password_slc = htmlentities($password_trim);

                $password_password = htmlspecialchars($password_slc);

            //-------------------------------------------------------------------//

            //Encriptamos las claves de acceso

                $usuario_hash = hash('sha512', $usuario_usuario);

                $password_hash = hash('sha512', $password_password);


                $vld_cmc = $mbd->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) id FROM comercios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND password = :password");

                $vld_cmc->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario_hash);

                $vld_cmc->bindParam(':password', $password_hash);

                $vld_cmc->execute();

                $registros_obtenidos_comercios = $vld_cmc->fetchColumn();

                    switch ($registros_obtenidos_comercios) {

                        case 0:

                                $error_login = 'Tu usuario y/o clave no coinciden con nuestros registros. Intentalo de nuevo';

                        break;

                        case 1:

                                //Empezamos la creacion de sesiones e insercion de ingreso a la db

                                $slct_dt_comercio = $mbd->prepare("SELECT * FROM comercios WHERE usuario = :usuario AND password = :password");

                                $slct_dt_comercio->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario_hash);

                                $slct_dt_comercio->bindParam(':password', $password_hash);

                                $slct_dt_comercio->execute();

                                while ($dt_cmc = $slct_dt_comercio->fetch()){

                                    $nombre_empresa_usuario_comercio = $dt_cmc['nombre_empresa'];

                                    $nombre_empresa_usuario_con_comercio = $dt_cmc['nombre_empresa_con'];

                                    $codigo_identificacion_usuario_comercio = $dt_cmc['codigo_identificacion'];

                                }


                                    $_SESSION['nombre_empresa'] = $nombre_empresa_usuario_comercio;

                                    $_SESSION['codigo_identificacion_comercio'] = $codigo_identificacion_usuario_comercio;

                                    $_SESSION['confirm_access'] = 'true';

                                header("Location: ../panel/");

                            exit();



                        break;

                    }


        } //Termina Empty

    } //Termina validador datos recibidos POST

} //Termina validador acceso Boton?>
```

Comment: ¿Los registros que tienes en tu base de datos (usuario y password) ambos están encriptados?

Answer (score -1):

Primero los `header()` te van a estar mandando error pues ya se han mandado para cuando entra a ese controlador, te recomiendo que lo redirijas con js, en cuanto a la seguridad las normas basicas con desarrollos de PHP puro son:

- Escapado completo de datos: No dejar ningun dato sin verificar haciendo uso de `addslashes()`, `mysql_escape_string`, entre otros
- Hacer uso siempre de sentencias preparadas, nunca dejes que un dato pase directo de tu vista a tu BD ya que puede contener informacion maliciosa
- Haz uso de POO para el desarrollo de tus clases
- Haz uso de DAO para PHP
- Usa procedimiento de SQL, Triggers, views
- Encripta información sensible como contraseñas
- Usa Cookies y Sessions para verificar la informacion todo el tiempo
- Desarrolla en dos partes BackEnd y FrontEnd de preferencia con el uso de API REST
- No liberes datos sin antes haber validado quien esta solicitando
- Limita solicitudes desde sitios de terceros
- Configura tu htaccess
- Configura firewall, dns y ssl en tu servidor
- Usa validaciones de dos puntos y tokenx JWT

Con esas caracteristicas puedes sacar un buen producto a produccion, igual puedes usar frameworks para mejorar el desempeño y seguridad y usar recaptcha para formularios

Comment: Hola Ivan! Gracias por tu comentario! Al codigo que escribi, que vulnerablidad le ves? Inyeccion SQL, XSS, Cross-Site Scripting o alguna otra?

Comment: Lo unico que creo que le falta para ser aun mas seguro es DAO y POO, solo separar tus funciones en objetos, de ahi en mas el codigo esta bien.

Comment: Y que diferencia habria si no utilizo DAO y POO en mi codigo?

Comment: En cuestiones practicas no mucho, sin embargo pensando a futuro y escalabilidad con mas funciones entonces se hara mas complicado ya que el codigo quedara "regado" o redundante, en cuestiones de seguridad considera que POO puede encapsular informacion haciendo que sea mas dificil interceptarla mientras que DAO deja un unico camino de entrada a los datos lo cual hace que sea mas seguro, sin embargo si quieres salir a produccion rapido puedes hacerlo asi como lo tienes nada mas siempre escapando datos y haciendo queries preparadas.

Comment: Gracias Amigo, me solucionarias la vida si incluirias en mi codigo el DAO y POO

Comment: Mira te dejo mas o menos como es la funcionde DAO (al final solo son clases, funciones y objetos)

Comment: Bueno! Gracias Amigo

Comment: [Aqui](https://www.mediafire.com/file/sy54m96i4zygmqy/daotypes.php/file) puedes descargar un ejemplo de DAO que hice para un curso de PHP con POO, veras que lo unico que hace es la conexion y recopilacion de informacion de la BD con funciones predeterminadas y las retorna en un arreglo independiente, que podemos resaltar de ello, facil, con la funcion constructor creamos la conexion y empezas seteamos variables, con el destructor se elimina la conexion, para llamar al destructor debes hacer unset($object) desde la clase externa que instancia al DAO, espero haberme dado a entender

Comment: Gracias de verdad Amigo!